# Python classes with __hash__ support (depending on the instance)

Tags: python, hash, python-3.4

I have a mutable class in Python which I would like to be able to "freeze", at that point its immutable, therefor can have a `__hash__` function.

My concern is, will having the `__hash__` function present will make Python behave strangely because it may check for the existence of a hash function.

I realize I could use a subclass that has a hash function, copy the class to a subtype. But I'm interested to know if having an *optional* hash function is supported by Python.

In the example below it works in basic cases (but may fail in others).

Note: *This assumes you don't touch `_var` or `_is_frozen` directly and only use access methods.*

Note: its probably more Pythonic not to use this method and instead have a `FrozenMyVar` class, but Im curious if this can be considered to be *supported* in Python or not.

```
class MyVar:
    __slots__ = ("_var", "_is_frozen")

    def __init__(self, var):
        self._var = var
        self._is_frozen = False

    def freeze(self):
        self._is_frozen = True

    def __hash__(self):
        if not self._is_frozen:
            raise TypeError("%r not hashable (freeze first)" % type(self))
        return hash(self._var)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.val == other.val
        except:
            return NotImplemented

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        if self._is_frozen:
            raise AttributeError("%r is frozen" % type(self))
        self._var = value


# ------------
# Verify Usage

v = MyVar(10)
v.var = 9

try:
    hash(v)
except:
    print("Hash fails on un-frozen instance")

v.freeze()

try:
    v.var = 11
except:
    print("Assignment fails on frozen instance")

print("Hash is", hash(v))
```

---

Adding a note on the real-world use-case, We have some linear math module with Vector/Matrix/Quaternion/Euler classes. In some cases we want to have for eg, a "set of matrices" or a "dict with vector keys". Its always possible to expand them into tuples but they take up more memory & loose their abilities to behave a our own math types - so the ability to *freeze* them is attractive.

Answer (score 4):

The original example didn't quite work "sensibly", because the class had `__hash__` but not `__eq__`, and as [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**hash**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) says "If a class does not define an **eq**() method it should not define a **hash**() operation either".  But the OP's edit fixed that side issue.

This done, if the class and its instances are indeed used with the discipline outlined, behavior should comply with the specs: instances are "born unhashable" but "become hashable" -- "irreversibly" given said discipline, and only, of course, if their `self.val` is in turn hashable -- once their `freeze` method is called.

Of course `collections.Hashable` will "mis-classify" unfrozen instances (as it only checks for the presence of `__hash__`, not its actual working), but that is hardly unique behavior:

```
>>> import collections
>>> isinstance((1, [2,3], 4), collections.Hashable)
True
>>> hash((1, [2,3], 4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

That `tuple` does appear "hashable", like all tuples (since its type does define `__hash__`) -- but if you in fact try `hash`ing it, you nevertheless get a `TypeError`, as one of the items is a `list` (making the whole not actually hashable!-).  Not-yet-frozen instances of the OP's class would behave similarly to such a tuple.

An alternative which does avoid this little glitch (yet doesn't require potentially onerous copies of data) is to model the "freezing" as the instance "changing type in-place", e.g...:

```
class MyVar(object):
    _is_frozen = False

    def __init__(self, var):
        self._var = var

    def freeze(self):
        self.__class__ = FrozenMyVar

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.val == other.val
        except:
            return NotImplemented

    __hash__ = None

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        if self._is_frozen:
            raise AttributeError("%r is frozen" % type(self))
        self._var = value


class FrozenMyVar(MyVar):
    _is_frozen = True

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._var)
```

This behaves essentially like the original example (I've removed the "slots" to avoid issues with `object layout differs` errors on `__class__` assignment) but may be considered an improved object model since "changing type in-place" models well such irreversible changes in behavior (and as a small side effect `collections.Hashable` now behaves impeccably:-).

The concept of an object "changing type in-place" freaks some out because few languages indeed would even tolerate it, and even in Python of course it's a rare thing to have a practical use case for such an obscure feature of the language.  However, use cases do exist -- which is why `__class__` assignment is indeed supported!-)

Comment: Well spotted, `__eq__` part was an oversight (corrected), actual example is much longer (and has an `__eq__`).

Comment: Good to know its supported, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @ideasman42, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__ : "The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value" (followed but many instances of "should", but by definition "should" in a standard is strongly advisory, not rigidly normative).  A sea lawyer might dispute whether the required behavior is perfectly matched (it surely would if equality of `_is_frozen` was also required, rather than just equality of `_val`) but I would argue it still is (too long a discussion for here:-).